# Keep the account info in all activities in android studio

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-intent, android-studio

My application is simply a managing database application. I have a remote mysql server set up and my android studio application uses http post request to connect to that server.

Supposed I want to keep the account information like username, password in all activities. Right now I use the putExtra() to transfer and keep the account information in all activities but it seems complicated. Every time I start a new activity and I need the putextra() to transfer my account information, is there a easy and better way to accoumplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many options:

1) Create a global class with static variables.

2) Extend the Application class and store information in it.

2) If it's just two-three parameters, you can store it in shared preferences.

Comment: public class Account {
    public static String eamil;
    public static String password;
} something like this for the first approach?

Comment: @KKKK :  yes. something like that

Answer (score 1):

you could it done in many ways like store data in sharedpreference or database or simply create a class that contains static variables.

To store and get data from shared preference use this.

```
public class MyPreference {

SharedPreferences myPrefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor;
Context context;

// ------------------------------------------------------------------costructor
public MyPreference(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    myPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0);
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------- user login

public void setLogin() {

    prefEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    prefEditor.putBoolean("login", true);
    prefEditor.commit();

}

public boolean isLogin() {
    return myPrefs.getBoolean("login", false);
}

public void setPassword(String userPass) {
    prefEditor = myPrefs.edit();
    prefEditor.putString("user", userPass);
    prefEditor.commit();
}

public String getPassword() {
    return myPrefs.getString("user", "");
}
}
```

Comment: I think accessing database in every activity can be costly.

Comment: accessing database itself is costly, as compared to getting data from a static file.