# Android: How to access same object in all other non activity class?

Tags: android, android-activity

In my android application i am setting some value in one activity(Activity A) class and i am getting those values in another non activity class(Non Activity B). My issue is to get those set values i need the same object by which i had set in Activity A. How to get the same object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to share data between activities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878159/whats-the-best-way-to-share-data-between-activities)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep the account info in all activities in android studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472137/keep-the-account-info-in-all-activities-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static object to share among all application.

Answer (score 0):

For achieving it, you can use Intent , static fields , singleton or local storage like shared preference or sqlite.