# How to keep a session in android using cookies?

Tags: android, session, cookies

In need my application to login and keep the same session id until i logout. in mij login i use this:

```
     public class loginTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String loginData = params[0];
                String text = "";
                BufferedReader reader = null;

                // Send data
                try {
                    // Defined URL  where to send data
                    URL url = new URL(URL);

                    // getting cookies:
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    conn.connect();

                    // setting cookies
                    cookieManager.setCookies(url.openConnection());
                    cookieManager.storeCookies(conn);
}
```

when the application is automatically logged in, it needs to send some data to a different URL:

```
Public class sendVisumNo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String visumNo = params[0];
            String text = "";
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Send data
            try {
                // Defined URL  where to send data
                URL send_visum_url= new URL(SEND_VISUM_URL);

                // getting cookies:
                conn = loginURL.openConnection();
                conn.connect();

                // setting cookies
                cookieManager.setCookies(loginURL.openConnection());
                cookieManager.storeCookies(conn);
}
```

How can i give the SEND_VISUM_URL the same cookie/session id as the first one? until i logout

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: apologies never done this before, but couldn't you save cookie information to a file. Then open it up during auto login if available and if fails then login as normal?

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35472180/4146722

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to do that
[This is more complete answer to shared preferences.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

```
private SharedPreferences preferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
preferences = getSharedPreferences("com.example.yourpackagename.bla", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`
```

Storing data:

```
String cookies="someweirdbigstring";
editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("cookies",cookies);
editor.apply()
```

Retrieving data:

```
String cookies = preferences.getString("cookies", null);
if (cookies!=null){
    //Do stuff with cookies
}else{
    // No cookies
}
```

Comment: thanks, but how do i assign the sessionid from cookieManager.setCookies(url.openConnection()); to the other URLconnection?

Comment: I updated  my answer on how you retrieve the data. Hope that helps.